# Active Record find from factory girl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, factory-bot

Im trying to implement a database-based sequence generator in rails so i wrote a code that goes something like

```
@semaphore.synchronize {
 seq = Sequence.find_by_name(type)
 seq.value += 1
 seq.save

 val = seq.value
 unless prefix.nil?
   "#{prefix}-#{val}"
 else
   "#{val}"
 end
}
```

My question is, is it possible to setup the initial sequence data using factory girl and be able to access it using Sequence.find_by_name or fixture loading is my only option? i.e. `rake db:fixtures:load RAILS_ENV=test FIXTURES_PATH=spec/fixtures`?

Thanks

Comment: You are aware rails uses a sequence by default for the id? But if you need an "extra" unique value, based on another sequence, and this code is in your model, triggered on `before_create` factory-girl should just use it and just work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i was able to find the answer.

I created my Sequence definition in factory girl as below:

```
FactoryGirl.define do

  factory :membership_sequence, class: Sequence do
    name  'membership'
    value 1
  end

  factory :payment_sequence, class: Sequence do
    name  'payment'
    value 1
  end
end
```

Then, in the before(:all) I called the create() method

```
before(:all) do
  # create the sequences
  create(:membership_sequence)
  create(:payment_sequence)
end
```

and voila! the Sequence.find_by_name shall work now.

To answer your question why i choose to implement sequence generation manually than using rails active record autogenerated ids, it's because i want to be able to generate sequences such as PREFIX-2015-0001, PREFIX-2016-0001